# Temporary ASP.NET files & TeamCity

Tags: asp.net, .net, teamcity, temporary-files

Our TeamCity agent machines have been struggling for disk space recently. I did a little snooping on each of the machines to find that the Temporary ASP.NET folder in the .NET installation directory was taking up more than 10GB of space on each box, each folder comprising of about 5MB each.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
```

I've done my research on the subject and I know that the files are a biproduct of ASP.NET's dynamic compliation, I also understand how IIS uses them for request optimisation (See: [Understanding ASP.NET Dynamic Compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx))

What I don't understand is why no one else is complaining about how these files are taking up disk space on their build servers when they really only need to be used on their web servers.

Surely someone out there has run into this problem before, can anyone offer me a solution other than

1. Disabling dynamic compliation (outlined [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/shravan/archive/2009/12/26/dynamic-compilation-of-asp.net-pages.aspx))
2. Doing a brute force scheduled job deletion (outlined [here](https://sysadminspot.com/server-administration/powershell-cleanup-temp-asp-net-files/))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had to settle for a PowerShell script that is run once a month as scheduled task, I followed Bredan's process outlined in this [SysAdminSpot post](https://sysadminspot.com/server-administration/powershell-cleanup-temp-asp-net-files/), with only a few modifications

Answer (score 1):

These files are created when a website is actually run under IIS.  They are not created when it is built and should not be on your build server.  I am using TeamCity to build websites and do not have this issue.  The files are created on the webservers of course, but not the build server.

Are you launching the website (for UI unit testing) perhaps?

Comment: We're not launching the website on our build servers, only pulling the source from the VCS root and building the solution. The files are deployed to the web server and are then handled by IIS

Comment: There is something else going on, because those temporary files are not created when you build, only when the site is run!

Comment: Did you read the SysAdminSpot post?
We build our solution files using MSBuild on our build servers, I'm not sure if you take the approach but the Temporary ASP.NET files are a biproduct of dynamic compliation, compilation being the keyword here